# How to break on javascript call to reload?

Tags: javascript, debugging

On a webpage, my own, and several thirdparty javascripts are running.

Sometimes very early during a page load, I see a reload that I'm trying to track down.

Due to the large amount of code involved, it's non-trivial to go manually review all code, and some of the thirdparty stuff may be obfuscated anyway, so I'm looking for a way to [break](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint) when the browser is told to do a reload.

I know I could potentially narrow it down to individual files by divide and conquer, but even if I did, I could still be left with a single large file, so I'm strongly hoping I can find a way that provides me answers with greater precision than "that file".

Within reason, I'm willing to switch browser, install extensions, or write a bit of extra code, or something else, that allows me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If the reload is originated from Javascript (I'm assuming that it's a refresh, not an XMLHttpRequest), open the developer tools and search for `window.location`. Most of the reloads take place with the `location.reload()` method, or assigning an URL to the `window.location` and put a breakpoint in every occurance.

If you still can not figure out, search for `location` only since location is a member of the window object and every global member is treated as a member of the window object.

With this method, there is a big chance that you'll catch the library responsible from the reloads.

Comment: That sounds very hopeful, and I'll give it a go. I'm hoping though for a more precise method than searching the code. :) Potentially obfuscation could make it non-obvious what's happening, even though `window.location` is being used.